# How to avoid chopped result in BaseX?

Tags: xml, basex

When I open a large XML file (6MB) with BaseX, the result is being chopped. Only 1/3 of the XML is displayed, so it will look like this:

```
 ... 
 <node>
     <node>Text</node>
     <attrib...
```

When I try to make a full-file search, only the first third of the XML can be searched.

How can I disable chopped results in BaseX? I would like to display the *complete* XML in the result window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open *Options*, *Preferences*. Move the slider *Maximum number of hits* to the very right, which will completely disable result chopping in the graphical user interface.

[image: Maximum number of hits preference in BaseX]

Be aware that you might under degraded performance for very large result sets (6MB does not really seem overly large, though).

Comment: The slider _Maximum number of hits_ is already set to "All", but result is still chopped.

Comment: If it is, there seems to be a bug. Verify the issue still exists with the newest release of BaseX, and if it continues, open an issue at [BaseX' issue tracker](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues) explaining how to reproduce it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I found out, that the XML-file is not valid. I've used a XML Validator and the validator reported an missing attribute. It seems that this caused the chopped result.

Comment: BaseX does not _validate_ XML files, which would mean validating it against a schema or DTD file. BaseX only tests for well-formed XML files, but then again the result window shows XML generated by BaseX, which should always be well-formed anyway.